# Clarification on why this code is resulting in false and not true

Tags: java, truthtable

The following code results in false. Could anyone explain to me why? I am having some trouble understanding using truth tables. I am a beginner with java, thank you in advance for the help.

```
boolean x = false;
boolean y = true;
boolean z = true;

System.out.println((!x || y && !z));
```

I expected the printed line to be false but the correct answer is true.

Comment: _The following code results in false_ —No, it prints true.

Answer (score 5):

The factors that come into play here are operator precedence, left-to-right evaluation, and the special "short circuit" nature of '&&' and '||'.

'and' binds tighter than 'or'.

Firstly, operator precedence means the expression is effectively

```
  (  (!x) || (y && !z) );
```

Given the short-circuit execution of '||', once we know that `!x` is true, the right-hand side does not get evaluated.

I wrote this hack to print out each term as it was evaluated:

```
static boolean P(String s, boolean x) { System.out.println(" "+s); return x; }
```

and then replaced every boolean term 'b' to a call to P("b", b):

```
{
   ... same as before...
   System.out.println( P("!x",!x) || (P("y",y) && P("!z",!z)));
}
```

results in output

```
   !x
  true
```

note: nothing related to y or z printed.